WG-Dashboard нет ipv4 адреса при создании нового Пира
Подскажите пожалуйста, как в WG-dashboard добавить ipv4 адрес новым Пирам? Всё перерыл, вроде всё правильно.

Если создаю Пир через ssh с помощью команды ./wireguard-install.sh, то новому Пиру присваивается новый ipv4 и ipv6 адрес.

Вот мой wg0.conf

и файл params

При добавлении сюда диапазона ipv4 выдает ошибку и поломало файл wg.conf, перестали работать существующие Пиры, после восстановления wg.conf уже существующие пиры заработали.
Ошибку WG-dashboard отдавал такую:
Warning: `/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf' is world accessible [#] ip link add wg0 type wireguard [#] wg setconf wg0 /dev/fd/63 [#] ip -6 address add fd42:42:42::1/64 dev wg0 [#] ip -6 address add fd42:42:42::1/64 dev wg0 RTNETLINK answers: File exists [#] ip link delete dev wg0



добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

В итоге добавил адрес сюда, сломался снова файл wg0.conf, ввёл туда, что было до изменения, сохранил, перезапустил WG и теперь можно задавать ipv4 адреса. Возможно из-за строк в PostUP и PostDown ломается. Я там ничего не изменял, стоят дефолтные значения.

